# Saving DataTable to excel using EPPlus, not saving empty string over previous value

Tags: c#, datatable, xlsx, epplus, worksheet

I have an .xlsx file stored on my desktop that my C# program reads from, then it loads each worksheet into datatables that my program uses. When a modification is made to a dataTable, I save to the .xlsx file by first loading the datatable back into the worksheet, and then saving the excelPackage with the modified dataTable information.

The problem is, I sometimes need to overwrite a cell with a blank string, and after saving, the previous value is still there.

It will let me update a value to a space (" "), but I want to save the cell as empty, "", or null.

This is loading my dataTables from the .xlsx

```
            using (var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
        {
            try
            {
                using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath + "/dataSet.xlsx"))
                {
                    pck.Load(stream);
                }
                for (int i = 1; i < pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Count; i++)
                {
                    var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets[i];
                    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
                    foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
                    {
                        tbl.Columns.Add(true ? firstRowCell.Text : string.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column));
                    }
                    var startRow = true ? 2 : 1;
                    for (int rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
                    {
                        var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, ws.Dimension.End.Column];
                        DataRow row = tbl.Rows.Add();
                        foreach (var cell in wsRow)
                        {
                            row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
                        }
                    }
                    if (ws.Name == "customerDataTable") { _customerDataTable = tbl; }
                    else if (ws.Name == "vehicleDataTable") { _vehicleDataTable = tbl; }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

This is saving the dataTable information into worksheet, then to .xlsx

```
            string tableName = "";

        if (table == _customerDataTable) { tableName = "customerDataTable"; }
        else if (table == _vehicleDataTable) { tableName = "vehicleDataTable"; }

        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath + "/dataSet.xlsx");
        using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(file))
        {
            ExcelWorkbook excelWorkBook = excelPackage.Workbook;
            ExcelWorksheet excelWorksheet = excelWorkBook.Worksheets[tableName];
            excelWorksheet.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(table, true);

            excelPackage.Save();
        }
```

I got it to work following VDWWDs post, using the following code:

```
                for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < table.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    excelWorksheet.Cells[i+2,j+1].Value = table.Rows[i][j];
                }
            }
            //excelWorksheet.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(table, true);
```

I replaced the LoadFromTable() line with a nested For loop.  Although it functionally works, I'm going to be using this method a lot throughout my program, and this solution seems a bit bulky compared to EPPlus LoadFromTable method. I'm thinking there has to be a better way...

Comment: First thing I would do, is to remove the `catch` clause. Getting exception information is way more efficient than posting here on SO.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!  I edited the code, but there is no exception

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Using `ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "";` will overwrite the contents.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment. Im setting the cell to "" in the dataTable before loading it to the ExcelPackage.  With your solution, would I have to for loop through each cell in the dataTable to set each cell accordingly instead of using ws.LoadFromTable()?